# How to return data from KubernetesPodOperator

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

In dag script

```
result = KubernetesPodOperator(
    task_id=task_id,
    name=task_name,
    cmds=["pipenv", "run", "python3", "myscript.py"],
    env_vars=env_vars,
    image=image # docker image
)
```

In `myscript.py`, the result would be an integer

```
def myfunction():
    ''' Perform a series of operations '''
    return result

myfunction()
```

For certain reason, I need to run `myscript.py` in which it'll return a result needed by the dag. Using `env_vars`, data would be able to be passed from the dag script to `myscript.py` but how data can be passed back to the dag script? PS: I'm aware of `xcom` that can help to communicate between tasks but not sure if it applies for this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KubernetesPodOperator handles XCom values differently than other operators. In order to pass a XCom value from your Pod you must specify the do_xcom_push as True. This will create a sidecar container that runs alongside the Pod. The Pod must write the XCom value into this location at the /airflow/xcom/return.json path.

see this for [details](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/operators.html#how-does-xcom-work)